# LitePicker / date picker js - Adding an extra div inside the current anchor of the date

Tags: javascript, scope, datepicker, this

Im currently working on a little project and I have been asked to do some specific styling to a date picker - this date picker library is using LitePicker.js. The only issue is to do it i'd need an extra div inside the current anchor which contains the date.

Currently the html looks like this:

`<a href="#" class="day-item is-start-date" data-time="1591830000000">11</a>`

but I need it to look like this:

`<a href="#" class="day-item is-start-date" data-time="1591830000000"><span class="date">11</span></a>`

In the documentation there is no example on how I could do this via the api:

https://wakirin.github.io/Litepicker/

Would I be able to use the THIS method within the same scope to append a span tag to do this?

Here is the basics of the setup in CodePen:

https://codepen.io/nolimit966/pen/ZEQEawv

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will wrap the text of each selected element with a span tag:

```
for (let a of document.querySelectorAll("div.container__days a")) {
    a.innerHTML = "<span>" + a.innerText + "</span>"
}
```

The selector I choose (`"div.container__days a"`) is the one that works on https://wakirin.github.io/Litepicker/ but you can change it according to your needs.

The idea is simply to transform the HTML contained in the `a` tags to add a span.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Utopsia/pen/BajarVo

Note: I used a button to illustrate that the DOM has time to load before you can click on it, but you could also use a setTimeout. The idea is to give time to the DOM to be updated with the elements created by the Litepicker.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I have implemented that but it doesn't seem to work for me. The anchor still shows as <a href="#" class="day-item" data-time="1591052400000">2</a> with the missing span. Theres no console errors

Comment: This code works on the Litepicker github and on your codepen example, so I guess the problem is elsewhere. Can you share more code so I can try and see why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Hi Benjamin. Ive updated the codepen with your code just here: https://codepen.io/nolimit966/pen/ZEQEawv

Comment: That's because the code is run before the DOM is created I think. Give me a few minutes, I'll update your codepen and edit my answer.

Comment: Thats worked brilliant, thanks a lot Ben. I also improved it a little by using the litePicker function trigger rather than attaching to a button. :-)

Comment: Happy to hear that ! If it's good for you, you may accept the answer ?

Comment: Note: from 1.5.4 added new event `onShowTooltip`. https://jsfiddle.net/waki/9h6us0L2/ After choosing a start date, move mouse on 15-18 June to see the modified tooltip